# Passing a 2D Array from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner in using PHP and Javascript, and I don't have any idea on how to store the data that I've gathered from MySQL which I placed in a multidimensional array in PHP to a 2D array in Javascript. Here's my working code in PHP:

```
<?php

function connecToDatabase(){
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "p@ssword";
$database = "flood_reports";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());
}

function retrieveData(){
connecToDatabase();
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM entries') or die(mysql_error());
$entries = array(); 
$index = 0;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
    $entries[$index] = array('entry_id' => $info['entry_id'], 
    'location' => $info['location'], 
    'image_dir' => $info['image_dir'], 
    'longitude' => $info['longitude'], 
    'latitude' => $info['latitude'], 
    'level' => $info['level']);
    $index++;
}

$json = json_encode($entries);
echo $json;

mysql_close();
}

retrieveData();

?>
```

Comment: How is this PHP being executed, is it part of an entire HTML page or is this script requested via AJAX/XHTP?

Answer (score 1):

on the end of your script add the following

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          var jsvar = <?php echo $phpvar;?>
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo $json;
```

with

```
echo 'var fromPhp = ' . $json . ';';
```

You just need to put the data into a variable.  This will make it available as fromPhp on the browser side.